# UITextField return key to make change in ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield

I have a `ViewController` with `String` variable  called `query` and numerous `UITextField` each with their own separate delegate Swift file since they each have different behavior.

One thing that is common amongst the `UITextField` is that I'd like to set `query` equal to `textField.text` when the user hits the return key.

I figure that this should occur under each delegate file's `textFieldShouldReturn` method, however I am unclear on how to pass `textField.text` back to `ViewController` and set it to `query` inside each delegate Swift file...

Comment: Are all these text fields in the same controller that has the `query variable?`

Comment: Why does each text field have its own delegate? Show an example of one of the delegate classes.

Comment: Text fields can also have an IBAction, on "editing did end", for instance. You can connect all the text fields to one action, and get their text from there.

Comment: Yes, each `textField` is in the same VC as `query`.  Each `textField` is a search field, one field searches tags based on the user input text (this gets set to `query`), and the other two are for coordinates (one for latitude, one for longitude) and they have their own `var` as well (`latVal` and `lonVal`)  Also second two fields have methods to restrict text to numbers - and .  This is why I have two delegate class files - `SearchFieldDelegate.swift` and `LocFieldDelegate.swift`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use notificaiton like this
 In `viewDidAppear`

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"didChanged:" , name: UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification, object: nil);
```

Then

```
func didChanged(notification:NSNotification){
    //notification conatins your textfield info
    let textfield = notification.object as! UITextField
}
```

Do forget to remove observer in `viewDidDisappear`

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification, object: nil)
```